# Add attribute when serializing object with XStream

Tags: java, xml-serialization, xstream

I am using XStream to serialize Java objects to XML. Is it possible to customize XStream so that when it serializes an object it inserts an attribute in the root XML element?

Let's say I have

```
class A{
 int foo = 1;
}
```

I want XStream to serialize instances of A to look like:

```
<A type="text/xml">
 <foo>1</foo>
</A>
```

Where the attribute text/xml is automatically added to the root element.

My use case is serializing my java object and insert it as the content element inside Atom entry documents. The end result would look like:

```
<feed>
<content type="text/xml">
<foo>1</foo>
</content>
</feed>
```

I do not require being able to unmarshall the feed. I need a generic solution that is agnostic to the class of the object I am serializing.

Can I achieve this with XStream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way are the the `XStream.useAttributeFor(...)` methods.

This would force you to configure XStream for each object type you are using though, thus not agnostic.

So I don't think XStream is the tool you need.